# Transferring load to GPU during D3 animations

Tags: animation, canvas, d3.js, gpu

I am working on D3 canvas graphs; I want to increase frame rate, for that purpose I am thinking to offload the animation related code to GPU from CPU. Following articles on this topic can be found on the internet:

[Offloading Computation to your GPU](http://www.centerspace.net/blog/nmath-premium/offloading-computation-to-your-gpu/)

[Taking advantage of GPU acceleration in the 2D canvas](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/07/Taking-advantage-of-GPU-acceleration-in-the-2D-canvas)

[Unleash the Power of Hardware-Accelerated HTML5 Canvas](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/client/unleash-the-power-of-hardware-accelerated-html5-canvas.html#fbid=JQtHUA_DR0E)

But I couldn't apply anything, moreover I don't know how to implement and where to implement this code.

Any other suggestions for offloading the load to GPU from CPU are also welcome.